# Unix Sorting Problem

Tags: unix

My sorting doesn't work for numbers (k3 to k6) but it works for  k1 and k2 which are alphabets. How to sort for k3 to k6? Thanks for you help.

data:

MacOS X for dummies:Mary Abraham:53.48:88:38

code:

awk -F":" '{ printf "%-30s %-20s %-10.2f %-10d %-10d %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, "$"$3 * $5  }' BookDB.txt | sort -nk3

format:"TITLE |                        AUTHOR  |             PRICE  |    QTY AVBL |  QTY SOLD |  TOTAL SALES"

Comment: Not sure if this is available on Mac OS' version of sort but you can specify the separator field to ":" instead of the default whitespace:

sort -t':' -n -k3,3

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the spaces in the book title and author name are causing sort to miscount the columns,  If you print a seperator character like '|' between each field in awk, then you can use sed to temporarily replace all the spaces like so,

| sed -e 's/ /#/g' -e 's/|/ /g' | sort -nk3 | sed -e 's/ /|/g' -e 's/#/ /g'